# shared_ptr::reset only works with raw pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, shared-ptr

I have always seen the smart pointer `reset` function used with raw pointers. When I try to pass another smart pointer to it, it fails. I looked here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset
but it does not say much about this. Just want to confirm if this is the case? My code is here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/xKNtJhjGeOSZS7KN
Also here for your convenience:

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;
#include<memory>
using std::shared_ptr;

class Widget
{
public:
  ~Widget()
  {
    cout << "Hi from destructor" << endl;
  }
};

auto wdel = [](Widget* pw)
            {
              cout << "Hi from custom deleter" << endl;
              delete pw;
            };

int main()
{
  {
    shared_ptr<Widget> pw(nullptr,wdel);
    pw.reset(new Widget);
    cout << "Done reset" << endl;
    shared_ptr<Widget> pw2(nullptr,wdel);
    // pw = pw2;   // this works
    pw2.reset(pw); // this does not work
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "[..] but it does not say much about this"  it says that `reset` takes a `T*` as parameter....

Comment: Oh, I thought you can pass a smart pointer to a function expecting a raw pointer? Or is there no implicit conversion?  Sorry, I've never used smart pointers before. I think this is the case though (that there's no implicit conversion), thank you!

@tobi303 - do you want to reply with that so I can accept your answer? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pw2 = pw` is the correct thing, and only copies (using `shared_ptr::operator&` or `shared_ptr::shared_ptr`) can be correct.

Consider if there were a third `shared_ptr`. That has as much right to keep the ownership as `pw`, so `pw` can't be allowed to transfer ownership somewhere else.

You can do `pw2 = pw; pw.reset(nullptr);` to release `pw`s ownership to `pw2`, because that doesn't affect other pointers sharing the Widget.

Answer (score 3):

Implicit conversion from smart pointers to raw pointers is very dangerous.  So it doesn't happen.

If a smart pointer thinks it is managing a pointer that another smart pointer is managing, both will think they have the right to clean it up.  And bad things will usually happen when the second one does the cleanup.

A raw pointer doesn't contain ownership information.

On the other hand, when you assign one shared pointer to another, the information about the lifetime of the pointer is also shared.  So the two cooperatively manage the pointers lifetime, and the last one to leave skope does the cleanup.